# how can map an array in a object from state vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have some object in items array and in that objects, there is an array, I've filtered values of objects but the array that is located on it didn't filter I know its natural, but I don't know how can I map or filter the array, anyone can help me?

Here my vuex store codes:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0,
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: "Jack", age: 19, favs: ["Football", "Game"] },
            { id: 2, name: "Tom", age: 20, favs: ["Basketball", "Swiming"] },
        ],
    },
    getters: {
        filterItems(state) {
            return state.items.filter((item) => item);
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        increment(state) {
            state.count++;
        },
        decrement(state) {
            state.count--;
        },
    },
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
});
```

here html codes:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>Age:</th>
      <th>Favs:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody v-for="(item, index) in filterItemsShow" :key="index">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.favs }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and vuejs codes:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    filterItemsShow() {
      return this.$store.getters.filterItems;
    },
  },
```

Comment: Isn't that easier to ask google how to filter array?

Comment: @bülent-akgül  I didn't find an answer, I think you did not understand what I meant, I have an array in my favs array that I gonna filter it but I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, instead of this line code :

```
 <td>{{ item.favs }}</td>
```

add below line code:

```
<td v-for="(i,index) in item.favs" :key="index">{{ i }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<td>{{ item.favs }}</td>
```

use

```
<td>{{ filterFavs(item.favs) }}</td>
```

In methods

```
filterFavs(favs) {
  let filteredFavs = favs.filter(fav => // filter with your criterias);
  return filteredFavs.join(", ")
}
```